# ReConvert bytes to a file Python

Tags: python, binary, type-conversion, byte

For a personal project i would like to convert files of any types (pdf, png, mp3...) to bytes type and then reconvert the bytes file to the original type.
I made the first part, but i need help for the second part.

In the following example, I read a .jpg file as bytes and i save its content in the "content" object. Now i would like to reconvert "content" (bytes type) to the original .jpg type.

```
test_file = open("cadenas.jpg", "rb")
content = test_file.read()
content
```

`b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x0 ...`

Could you help me ?

Regards

Comment: If you haven't changed the content you can write it back to file with `wb` mode.  However the file types you have mentioned are structured formats, so if you have changed them they may not work as the original file type.

Comment: @yannvm There's no string involved here that needs to be converted.

Comment: @K J In my case I’m just using « .read » and « .write » from the @Yannvm ‘s answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pictures uses Base64 encoding.
This should do the job.

```py
import base64

test_file = open('cadenas.jpg', 'rb')
content = test_file.read()

content_encode = base64.encodestring(content)
content_decode = base64.decodebytes(content_encode) 

result_file = open('cadenas2.jpg', 'wb')
result_file.write(content_decode)
```

Comment: It was exactly what i needed thanks you for your help.